# jquery ui slider hidden input won't update on event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I try to update my hidden input field inside jquery ui slider but won't happen. I have been using the following code. Checking the DOM with Firebug input field does not get updated on event. Initial values are shown.

```
 // --- Price Slider
        $("#price_slider").each(function() {
            $(this).slider({
                animate: true,
                step: 25,
                range: true, min: <?= $sel_minmax['price_min'] ?>, max: <?= $sel_minmax['price_max'] ?>,
                values: [<?= $params['price_min'] . ',' . $params['price_max'] ?>],
                change: function() {

                    // get slider values
                    var lower = $(this).slider("values", 0);
                    var upper = $(this).slider("values", 1);

                    // update spans with slider values
                    $(this).children("a.ui-slider-handle").first().children("span").html(lower + '€');
                    $(this).children("a.ui-slider-handle").last().children("span").html(upper + '€');
                }

            });
            $("input[id=price]").val($("#price_slider").slider("values", 0) + ";" + $("#price_slider").slider("values", 1));
            $(this).children("a.ui-slider-handle").html("<span class='Slider_Value'></span>");
        });
```

html

```
<p>
        <span class="min"></span>
        <span class="max"></span>
        <input type="hidden" id="price" />
</p>

<div id="price_slider"></div><br>
```

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/aTLGA/2/

Comment: Please post your HTML and create a jsFiddle.

Comment: You have `$("#price_slider").each(function() {` which implies you have used an ID more than once. Can't do that.

Comment: okay I see now what you mean. Using stead classes would be a better approach? Or the hole stuff need to be re-factorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's only the hidden input field that don't update? I think that if you change your code for something like this it will work:

```
$(function() {
  // --------------------------------
        // --- Price Slider
        $("#price_slider").each(function() {
            $(this).slider({
                animate: true,
            step: 25,
            range: true, min: 1200, max: 5000,
            values: [1200 , 5000],
            change: function() {

                // get slider values
                var lower = $(this).slider("values", 0);
                var upper = $(this).slider("values", 1);

                // update spans with slider values
                $(this).children("a.ui-slider-handle").first().children("span").html(lower + '€');
                $(this).children("a.ui-slider-handle").last().children("span").html(upper + '€');
                $("input[id=price]").val(lower+";"+upper);
            }

        });

        $(this).children("a.ui-slider-handle").html("<span class='Slider_Value'></span>");
    });


});
```

was that your problem?